# Trouble with Runge-Kutta Method for Coulomb's Law

Tags: python, physics, runge-kutta

I am trying to simulate a two-dimensional two charge situation using Euler's Method and the Runge-Kutta 4th Order Method. I have gotten relatively expected answers using both methods. But I had never tried using my RK4 method with different initial conditions.

Starting with a positive initial velocity vx0 and a negative initial x-position x0, the code seems to work just fine. But when I flip them so that vx0 is negative and x0 is positive, I get different answers, when they should be symmetric.

I made sure that my Euler method worked for both variations of initial conditions to confirm that it was my RK4 function that was the problem. I struggled initially to apply the RK4 method for two dimensional motion, so it doesn't surprise me that this error has come about. Below is an image that might make the problem a bit clearer.

[image]

Here is where I calculate the constants:

```py
# Initial conditions
time[0] = t = t0
vx1[0] = vx = vx0
vy1[0] = vy = vy0
x1[0] = x = x0
y1[0] = y = y0

for i in range(1, n + 1):
    # Calculate our constants
    k1vx = step * ax(x, y, q1, q2, m)
    k1vy = step * ay(x, y, q1, q2, m)
    k1x = step * vx
    k1y = step * vy
    k2vx = step * ax(x + 0.5 * k1x, y + 0.5 * k1y, q1, q2, m)
    k2vy = step * ay(x + 0.5 * k1x, y + 0.5 * k1y, q1, q2, m)
    k2x = step * (vx + (k1vx / 2))
    k2y = step * (vy + (k1vy / 2))
    k3vx = step * ax(x + 0.5 * k2x, y + 0.5 * k2y, q1, q2, m)
    k3vy = step * ay(x + 0.5 * k2x, y + 0.5 * k2y, q1, q2, m)
    k3x = step * (vx + (k2vx / 2))
    k3y = step * (vy + (k2vy / 2))
    k4vx = step * ax(x + k3x, y + k3y, q1, q2, m)
    k4vy = step * ay(x + k3x, y + k3y, q1, q2, m)
    k4x = step * (vx + k3vx)
    k4y = step * (vy + k3vy)

    # Update the values based on our calculated constants
    vx1[i] = vx = vx + (k1vx + k2vx + k2vx + k3vx + k3vx + k4vx) / 6
    vy1[i] = vy = vy + (k1vx + k2vy + k2vy + k3vy + k3vy + k4vy) / 6
    x1[i] = x = x + ((k1x + 2 * k2x + 2 * k3x + k4x) / 6)
    y1[i] = y = y + ((k1y + 2 * k2y + 2 * k3y + k4y) / 6)

    # Update the time
    time[i] = t = t0 + i * step
```

Here are the functions that I use for ax and ay in the previous code

```py
def accel_rk4_x(x, y, q1, q2, m):
    const = (q1 * q2) / (4 * math.pi * 8.854e-12 * m)
    return const * (x / ((x ** 2 + y ** 2) ** 1.5))


def accel_rk4_y(x, y, q1, q2, m):
    const = (q1 * q2) / (4 * math.pi * 8.854e-12 * m)
    return const * (y / ((x ** 2 + y ** 2) ** 1.5))
```

I appreciate any help with this problem! I might just need a second pair of eyes.

Comment: Could you first try some established RK4 code, like [scipy-RK4](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.RK45.html) or [this one](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Runge-Kutta_method#Python) just to make sure your implementation is working correctly?

Comment: `vy1[i] = vy = vy + (**k1vx** + k2vy + k2vy + k3vy + k3vy + k4vy) / 6` - hmm, typo?

Comment: @Joe I didn't even know SciPy had an RK4 built-in function. I'm kind of new to this. Thank you so much.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog I figured I had a typo, but I had looked at it for so long and couldn't see it. That solved everything. Thank you.

Comment: @Joe: As the first link string itself shows, it is RK45, the adaptive-stepsize Dormand-Prince 5(4) method, not the classical 4th order fixed-step RK4 method. Searching for RK4 on this portal should lead to several implementations and their pitfalls. The second link is RK4, but for a scalar ODE, not really useful to replace the code for the ODE system here. The component-wise expansion to a method for a system here already was correct, up to a typo, and is as good as it gets for a non-vectorized version.